# How to merge my local files to remote one?

Tags: git

I did a big mistake. I was not using Git so I edited my local files manually and when I wanted to add the last commits from community, I did it manually.

The problem is, I started using Git and after I cloned the master project I just deleted the whole stuff then paste my local with my changes to this folder, so when I try pull origin to master it says "up-to-date", even not being because theres alot of differences.

How can I "verify every single file and see the differences then merge them"?

Comment: Please describe the current state of both the local and remote repos. You can use `git log` to determine which commits are on each branch.

Comment: ye the problem is, for git all commits are in my local branch. I just deleted the folders/files and paste with my local folders/files changes. So i bypass git and he cannot see what is different between the local and remote

Comment: In addition, use `git status` to see what the state of the repository is. And `git diff` to see changes between HEAD and your current working directory. Also edit your question to show us the result of `git status`.

Comment: @GustavoMacedo You say you've deleted your git managed files and pasted in your own files. Git will therefore see that all the files it is tracking have been deleted (if you didn't paste in something with the same name in its place and in that case it will show you that the file has changed -- `git diff FILE_NAME`). See my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks! I found also another way to fix this, just connect my origin to a remote by using "git remote" then pull again so It overwrite the changed files